# Solve in $\mathbb{C}$ : $|z-i| = |z-1|$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I just had that question in my final exam

Solve in $\mathbb{C}$ :
 $|z-i| = |z-1|$

and I couldn't do it. I found a similar thread here : [Showing that $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1|<|z+i|\}$ is an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417401/showing-that-z-in-mathbbcz-1zi-is-an-open-set)
but it's too complicated for me to understand.

I tried 2 different ways to solve this

First, I developed the $z$ which gave me
$$\begin{align}
& (a+bi)-i=(a+bi)-1 \\
& = a-i+bi=a-1+bi \\
& = a-1(i+b)=a-1+bi \\
\end{align}
$$
However we are looking at the module of this, so i have to do
$\sqrt{((a^2)+(-1(i+b))^2} = \sqrt{((a-1)^2+(bi)^2)}$

Then I got some sort of $\sqrt{a^2-b^2-2ab}$ that equals to similar on the other side but couldn't find anything.

I tried the geometric way and the "logic" way (how can $i = 1$ when $i^2 = -1$), but I just don't understand how i'm suppose to solve this.

I also tried using the roots which say that
for $z^n = w$

$w = r^{(1/n)} \text{Ei}((\angle m \cdot \frac{2k\pi}{n}))$

Every formula I knew failed

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The geometric way is probably the simplest. The expression $|z-w|$ gives the distance between the points $z$ and $w$, so $z$ satisfying $|z-i|=|z-1|$ corresponds to a point which is equidistant from $1$ and $i$. (Or, in Cartesian coordinates, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$). But there's only one geometric figure corresponding to the set of points which are equidistant to two other points...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry. I tried to draw a cart to represent what you said : http://imgur.com/ZvXgX9l

But I don't quite get your point...Do you mean I need to calculate the hypothenuse of a right triangle?

Comment: @Maude I really don't understand what's in that diagram. And this really doesn't have much to do with right triangles (though I can see how it might appear so). The idea is simpler: If I pick two points, then in general any other point in the plane will be closer to one than the other. How would you represent that idea in a drawing?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm very bad in geometry. If you pick 2 points, then the third one will make a triangle, no?

Comment: Given that this guessing game doesn't seem to be helpful, I'll just give say what I'm getting at: If I pick any two points, the set of points which is equidistant from both of them is the _straight line_ which lies halfway between them. If I had the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$, this would be the $y$-axis. In the complex plane, with points $z=1$ and $z=i$, this corresponds to the condition $\text{Re }z=\text{Im }z$ i.e. the line through the points $z=0$ and $z=1+i$ (both of which satisfy the equation under consideration.)

Answer (score 1):

Write $z = a + bi$. Then you are trying to find all $z$ for which 
$$\sqrt{a^2 + (b - 1)^2} = \sqrt{(a - 1)^2 + b^2}$$
Squaring both sides and expanding the squares, this becomes
$$a^2 + b^2 - 2b + 1 = a^2 - 2a + 1 + b^2$$
Subtracting $a^2 + b^2 - 1$ from both sides, this becomes
$$-2b = -2a$$
So we are reduced to $a = b$. All steps here are reversible, so we conclude that all complex numbers where $b = a$ satisfy the equality. Geometrically this is the line $y = x$, the points equidistant from $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I did but I was stuck at square rooting a^2+b^2-2b+1..I didn't know how to remove the root without messing up the equation. I guess I was on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works, you just made a mistake in algebra. The condition $|z-i|=|z-1|$ is equivalent to $|z-i|^2=|z-1|^2$. Plugging in $z:=a+bi$, this  is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align}
|a+bi-i|^2&=|a+bi-1|^2\\
\Longleftrightarrow\ |a+i(b-1)|^2&=|(a-1)+bi|^2.\\
\end{align}
$$
Using the identity $|x+iy|^2=x^2+y^2$ we get
$$
a^2+(b-1)^2=(a-1)^2+b^2.\tag1$$
Expanding (1) and simplifying gives you
$$a=b$$

Comment: Thanks! i'm really happy to know I wasn't wrong all along =)

Answer (score 0):

$$|z-i| = |z-1|$$

This says that the distance between $z$ and $i$ is equal to the distance between $z$ and $1$. That describes the perpendicular bisector of the segment with endpoints at $i$ and $1$.

The midpoint of that segment is $\frac 12(1+i)$.

The segment is parallel to the direction $i-1$.  The direction perpendicular to that is
$i(i-1) = -1-i$ since multiplying by $i$ is a rotation of $90^\circ$.

So the set of all points is described by
$$\text{(initial point) + $t$(direction of line)}$$

$$z = \frac 12(1+i) + t(-1-i)$$

$$z = \left(\frac 12 - t\right) + i\left(\frac 12 -t\right)$$
$$z = s + is$$